# How to solve for $x$ in the equation $y = (x + 25)^x$ where you know the value of $y$

Tags: exponentiation

I am trying to figure out how to solve for $x$ in the equation $y = (x + 25)^x$ for any known $y$.

For example, I know that in the example $2758547353515625 = (x + 25)^x$, the value of $x$ is 10.

Is there a way to solve for $x$ for any known $y$?

Comment: integer solution?

Comment: It may be worth noting that I derived the simplest form of this equation from the original equation of $y = \frac{(x + 25)^{x / 5}}{b}$ where both values $y$ and $b$ are known values.

Comment: @추민서 The final solution would be rounded down to the nearest integer.

Comment: Use Newton's method (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) to approximate a solution to as much precision as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Making the problem more general, you want to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=(x+a)^x-y$$

I shall assume $a>0$ and suppose that $y$ could be a huge positive number.

$f(x)$ varies very quickly and this is not good for any root-finding algorithm.

At the opposite, consider instead
$$g(x)=x \log(x+a)-\log(y)$$ which is much more linear.

I am very lazy and I shall expand as series to have
$$g(x)=x \log (a)+O\left(x^2\right)-\log(y)$$ which gives as an *estimate*
$$x_0=\frac{\log (y)}{\log (a)}$$ which will allow to start Newton method.

Let us take the case of $a=25$ and $y=1234567898765432123456789$. The iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 17.233582865360804139 \\
 1 & 15.056838056149540045 \\
 2 & 15.034341020407527174 \\
 3 & 15.034338495863187264 \\
 4 & 15.034338495863155457
\end{array}
\right)$$